# How can I get a SQL query to aggregate lists of results that correspond to the same name?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, listagg, string-agg

I was given the beginning of a SQL Query and am trying to adjust it to get the results we want. I have a large dataset that I want to have one line for each name and merchant id, and for the remaining 2 columns, I want the results to be in a list.  After looking on the internet for a while, it seemed that listagg might be my best bet (string_agg did not come up as a function when i tried it). I am very new to SQL and still have a lot to learn, so I could be missing something super obvious, and I apologize for that.

For example, I have :

| name | account_id | category_name | class_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jen | 1234 | google | commerce |
| jen | 1234 | shopify | site |
| jen | 1234 | ads | marketing |
| sam | 098 | google | feedback |
| sam | 098 | shopify | email |
| sam | 098 | facebook | spend |

I would like it to appear as:

| name | account_id | category_name | class_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jen | 1234 | google; shopify; ads | commerce; site; marketing |
| sam | 098 | google; shopify; facebook | feedback; email; spend |

My current query is:

```
SELECT
 a.name AS merchant_name
, a.account_id AS merchant_id
, listagg( ic.category_name, ';') AS category
, listagg( ai.class_name, ';') AS integration_name
FROM metrics.account_integrations ai
INNER JOIN metrics.accounts a ON ai.account_id = a.account_id
LEFT JOIN metrics.integration_categories ic ON ai.class_name = ic.integration_name
LEFT JOIN metrics.account_targets atar ON ai.account_id = atar.account_id
GROUP BY 1,2, ic.category_name, ai.class_name, a.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

It is currently creating multiple lines for names and ids based on each distinct category and class_name. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Quoted from the [sql] tag description: _"Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include [...] a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. [...]"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only need to `group by` `name` and `account id`.

```
select   name
        ,account_id
        ,listagg(category_name, '; ') as category_name
        ,listagg(class_name, '; ')    as class_name
from     t
group by name, account_id
order by name
```

| NAME | ACCOUNT_ID | CATEGORY_NAME | CLASS_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jen | 1234 | google; shopify; ads | commerce; site; marketing |
| sam | 98 | google; shopify; facebook | feedback; email; spend |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v5Cb5Zvx)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! This totally fixed the problem. I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! Please select the answer and vote it up.